# export complete TFS work item incl. history with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, tfs, export, history, tfs-workitem

I am working for a customer who is running a Dynamics AX project and is using TFS. I do have access to TFS and am able to check all the different work items - however, what I am missing is an overview to build metrics as the only way to get data into a table (Excel) does not allow me to get the history of a work item.

I am hence wondering how I could do this using PowerShell. I am completely new to this, accordingly step-by-step guidance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TFS Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1).

For example:

```
$serverUrl = "http://tfsServer:8080/tfs/Collection"
$workItemId = "1"

#Get the Work Item 
$workItem = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$($serverUrl)/_apis/wit/workitems/$($workItemId)?api-version=3.0" -UseDefaultCredentials -Method Get

#Print the revisions number
Write-Host $workItem.rev

#Get the specific revision details
$revision = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$($serverUrl)/_apis/wit/workitems/$($workItemId)/revisions/2?api-version=3.0" -UseDefaultCredentials -Method Get

#Print the Work Item details in the specific revision
Write-Host $revision.fields
```